# Failing to run JanusGraph and Hbase

Tags: hbase, janusgraph

I am trying to run JanusGraph and HBase using docker compose using containers. My HBase is running properly but I am getting this exception in JanuGraph:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740
```

I am starting the Gremlin server following the instructions on the JanusGraph website using this property file:

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=zookeeper
storage.port=2181

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

Have you seen this error before? 
Thank you

Comment: what is your hbase and janusgraph version?

Comment: i am using hbase 1.4.10 and janusgraph 0.4.0